# Need advice on how to save all stock changes for rpg game in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stock

I've been creating rpg game and now I'm doing stock-market for my players that they could buy and sell shares. Stock prices are random and stock prices changes every 20 minutes. So, every change I have to save in mysql in one field because I want to show players graph of last month's changes. For example. first stock price is 100$, then, after 2 hours field looks like: "100-105-98-125-149-135". So, for whole month it would be 3*24*30 = 2160 random numbers. I think I can do more optimal, maybe you have any ideas? Because I'm not sure what to do when month pass and etc. Thank you very much.

**btw**: my English is quite poor, so I can't tell you all my minds very properly, so sorry. But still I hope you understood smth. If not - ask. It will be pleasure to answer.

Comment: Is this a web based game or a desktop application?  If it's running server-side then I wouldn't think optimality of storage would be a huge concern.  If you used 4 bytes for each price, then a years worth of data for every stock on the NYSE and NASDAQ would be about 650 megs.  At that size I don't think database schema would impact performance much.  The simplest way of storing the data could be good enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend one table with the stock information and then another table as a transaction log with each stock price change as a record.  You can pull all the rows of a stock for the history and the most recent for the current price.

Comment: Great idea, thanks. I will absolutely use it if there is no other suggestions.